# CollectionView custom renderer: selected item background color not works

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I created a CollectionView custom renderer control because I need to disable scroll in some situations, however this control doesn't seem to change the background color of the selected item automatically. Coloring a selected item works fine if I use a CollectionView, but it doesn't in my custom control.

I set the global style in platform specific resource file:

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#00FF00</item>
<item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
<item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>
```

Here is the custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CollectionViewExt), typeof(CollectionViewCustomRenderer))]
namespace Vendo.Android.Renderers
{
 internal class CollectionViewCustomRenderer: CollectionViewRenderer
 {
     public CollectionViewCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
     {
     }

     public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
     {
         if (Element is CollectionViewExt collectionView && collectionView.IsScrollEnabled)
             return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
         else
             return false;
     }

     public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
     {
         if (Element is CollectionViewExt collectionView && collectionView.IsScrollEnabled)
             return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
         else
             return false;
     }
 }
}
```

Follow the xaml page code:

```
            <controls:CollectionViewExt x:Name="cvArticoli" 
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"   
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        IsScrollEnabled="{Binding IsScrollEnabled}"
                        Style="{StaticResource CollExtStyle}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListaArticoli}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding ArticoloModelCorrente, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding VisualizzaArticoli}"
                        ClassId="{Binding CatalogoVisualizzato}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticoliTemplateSelector}"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="2" 
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreArticoliCommand}">

            <controls:CollectionViewExt.EmptyView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label 
                        Margin="0,10"                            
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="Nessun articolo in lista."
                        TextColor="Gray"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </controls:CollectionViewExt.EmptyView>

            <controls:CollectionViewExt.ItemsLayout>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <Binding Path="CatalogoVisualizzato"/>
                    <Binding Path="ColonneCatalogo"/>

                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <converters:BoolToItemsLayoutConverter/>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                </MultiBinding>
            </controls:CollectionViewExt.ItemsLayout>
        </controls:CollectionViewExt>
```

Here is the app.xaml for collectionView Visual State Manager:

```
            <Style x:Key="CollExtStyle" TargetType="controls:CollectionViewExt">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Highlight}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Disabled}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: 1) What is the problem you are trying to solve by using a custom renderer? 2) Please show the custom renderer and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added more details in the question. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using native styles from the Xamarin.Android project and mix those with a Xamarin.Forms control and a custom renderer. Why don't you just use the Visual State Manager to [change the selected item color](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color)?

Comment: I added visual state manager, but selected row color still doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you're not applying the Visual States as described in the documentation, specifically this note from the documentation is important: **"The Style that contains the Selected VisualState must have a TargetType property value that's the type of the root element of the DataTemplate, which is set as the ItemTemplate property value."** If I find the time, I'll write up an answer unless you figure it out before that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the meantime, I try to find a solution.

Comment: I've found the solution. See my answer.

Comment: Great, I missed that you didn't set the `SelectionMode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Just set SelectionMode property of the CollectionView, like so:

```
        <controls:CollectionViewExt x:Name="cvArticoli" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Style="{StaticResource CollExtStyle}"
            IsScrollEnabled="{Binding IsScrollEnabled}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListaArticoli}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding ArticoloModelCorrente, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsVisible="{Binding VisualizzaArticoli}"
            ClassId="{Binding CatalogoVisualizzato}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticoliTemplateSelector}"                                                                                
            RemainingItemsThreshold="2" 
            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreArticoliCommand}">
```

Comment: I don't see where you've set the `SelectionMode`.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted old code...